# Errors while Copying Workbook using JExcel API

Tags: spreadsheet, jexcelapi, formulas

I am trying to copy a large Excel file with multiple worksheets and a ton of formulas using JExcel API; however, when I run the following code--

```
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);

WritableWorkbook wcopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/filename.xls"), w);
```

I receive the errors below...

```
>jxl.common.AssertionFailed
>>> at jxl.common.Assert.verify(Assert.java:37)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.SheetCopier.copySheet(SheetCopier.java:329)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.copy(WritableSheetImpl.java:1584)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.copyWorkbook(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:971)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.<init>(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:343)
>>> at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:339)
>>> at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:320)
>>> at shortcut.ModifyCell.getValue(ModifyCell.java:66)
>>> at shortcut.ModifyCell.main(ModifyCell.java:88)

>Exception in thread "main" jxl.common.AssertionFailed
>>> at jxl.common.Assert.verify(Assert.java:37)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.SheetCopier.copySheet(SheetCopier.java:329)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.copy(WritableSheetImpl.java:1584)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.copyWorkbook(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:971)
>>> at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.<init>(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:343)
>>> at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:339)
>>> at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:320)
>>> at shortcut.ModifyCell.getValue(ModifyCell.java:66)
>>> at shortcut.ModifyCell.main(ModifyCell.java:88)
```

and a blank Excel file is created with the given name. I was wondering if there are any known limitations to copying spreadsheets with JExcel API--for example, formats or formulas that cannot be read, size limitations, macro limitations, etc?

(When I ran the code on their sample spreadsheet,  it copied perfectly fine, so I don't think it's a code issue, although I could be wrong.)

//Edit: Here are the warnings I received (multiple of each):

Reading...

Warning:  Property storage name for 5 is empty - setting to Root Entry

Warning:  Usage of a local non-builtin name

Copying...

Warning:  Shared template formula is null - trying most recent formula template

Warning:  Cell F155 already contains data

Warning:  Unknown shape typeWarning:  Unknown shape type

Warning:  Cell at H45 not present - adding a blank

Warning:  Cell at J45 not present - adding a blank

Warning:  Cell H45 already contains data

Warning:  Cell J45 already contains data

Answer (score 0):

Whenever JXL reads formulas, it will give you a logger warning. If you change all of the formulas to numbers, the warnings will go away.